# how do I disable or remove grunt tool in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

Does anyone know how to disable the grunt tool/runner in phpstorm?
Like most phpstorm tools, I'm sure it will be great when I have time to set aside to configure it, but I currently don't need it.
Its flashing error messages -saying thats its not configured properly and it seems to be actively trying to run grunt tasks.

I have tried:

1. to find the grunt runner in settings.
2. to find in "run debug" configuration
3. I checked to see if it was a plugin that could be removed - but it seems to be a core feature of phpstorm.
   .
   without any luck.

   #### error output from phpstorm's tray.

   grunt --no-color --gruntfile /var/www/html/project/Gruntfile.js --tasks /opt/PhpStorm-139.496/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/grunt_js/tasks _intellij_grunt_tasks_fetcher
   Cannot run program "grunt" (in directory "/var/www/html/projects"): error=2, No such file or directory

   Looks like the grunt command isn't in your system path.
   In order to view/run tasks, you need to install Grunt's command line interface globally:

   npm install -g grunt-cli

Comment: 1) Yes, it's part of JavaScript support plugin (AFAIK) 2) Please provide an example of such messages 3) I believe you may need to have grunt installed so that it can read tasks from gruntfile.js -- maybe this is what it complain about?

Comment: @LazyOne - thaks, 1) Yes it seems to be caused by javascript plugin 2) as requested error output included in to question now. 3) Yes grunt is installed globally, so Im not sure why that error is occuring. but my priority is to turn off the behaviour completely. i.e. its quite nerve racking to know that *if* phpstorm got its way it would run file modifying commands without me wanting it - or worse without me even being aware its doing it

Comment: 1) It does not execute any tasks without you telling it to do so -- it only tries to get list of tasks from gruntfile (it passes this job to grunt itself instead of parsing the file "manually") 2) I do not think that it's possible to disable gulp/grunt -- I see no such options at all 3) permission issue? or grunt file is not in the PATH? What OS do you have there -- Linux? How do you launch IDE (terminal or some "start menu" button)? Possibly IDE does not see whole PATH for some reason.

Comment: @LazyOne 1) interesting - relief :) 2) I dont see any config either 3) OS: Ubuntu 14.04. - Gruntfile is in path - i.e. if I take the command phpstorm is trying to run (you can see it there in the error output) - its runs fine when I run it from bash terminal - could be Permissions?

Comment: By *"or grunt file is not in the PATH?"* I meant grunt executable and not `gruntfile.js`. I'm not a Linux/Mac user .. so do not take my words too seriously, but it's possible that when launching IDE it does not see whole PATH (usually the case on Mac when launching it from launch panel -- works OK if launched from terminal). I guess `which grunt` and check permissions ... Try also launching IDE from terminal.

Comment: do you use NVM to manage Node? please try editing your launcher as suggested in http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5513463#5513463 - does it help?

Comment: @LazyOne Hah you were right - I normally use a desktop launcher to start phpstorm - I launched from a bash prompt and it works! Im wondering if the `$PATH` environment variable applies to the java/phpstorm process - differently than to my user account

Comment: @lena thanks for the link - I dont use NVM, but I was having the same problems as that person was. I tried their workaround i.e.  edit desktop launcher and set command to "/bin/bash -l -c "/path/to/webstorm.sh". This command will perform bash login after reading my .bashrc/.bash_profile files, then runs php/webstorm.sh - and that also works. So I guess issue was that when processes are launched from a account from within a shell they inherit the environment variables of the user? which makes sense because I have npm and grunt installed in unusual location